# How padding in stucture done in x64 systems.?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, structure

I have a doubt about padding and packing in structures, is padding same in both x86, x64 systems. can any one give me clear idea how memory padding done in both x86, x64.

```
struct mystruct_A {
   char a;
   int b;
   char c;
}v;
```

in my system (i3) its giving output as 12 for size of (v). how it will be done in both x64, x86.?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment... I do not know how anyone could word this better. It has all the details for each processor and how to calculate it (assuming your compiler uses the maximum word size).

Comment: Notice that the size of a `struct` may not be just the sum of elements' size.